# Hide "Upload Document" button via XML?

Tags: visual-studio, ribbon, xml

I'm trying to hide the "Upload Document" button (including the Upload Document and Upload Multiple Documents submenu). I've tried the following XML, but I can't get it to work:

```
  <CustomAction
    Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.AddDocument" />
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
  <CustomAction
    Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationId="0x0101" 
    RegistrationType="ContentType">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.AddDocument" />
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

Doing this removes the submenu, but makes the "New Folder" button, which I also have hidden, reappear:

```
<CustomAction
    Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationId="0x0101" 
    RegistrationType="ContentType">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.AddDocument.Menu.Upload" />
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

I want this button hidden because we have made our own file upload control and button and we no longer want the default SharePoint one to display.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I need the solution to be via XML. All of our Ribbon customizations are via XML, so using server-side code or CSS/JavaScript is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the SPRibbon class: http://www.3guysonsharepoint.com/?p=778

If you wish to remove multiple uploads use

```
Ribbon.Documents.New.AddDocument.Menu.Upload.UploadMultiple
```

The following is a walkthrough for Removing a Button from the Server Ribbon: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408060.aspx

Or, alternatively, you can use a css trick to hide them: http://www.patricktalmadge.com/2011/04/09/hide-multiple-upload-link-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thanks, but as you can obviously tell from my XML, I know how to remove a button from the ribbon. My question is how to remove this *particular* button via XML. Doing it through code is not an option because all of my other ribbon customizations are already XML based.